# how to derive the trigonometric polynomial in Fourier approximation

Tags: linear-algebra, fourier-series, fourier-transform

in the red square part of the formula, I have no idea how it becomes $\frac{1}{2\Pi}$ and also what does "function 1" mean? I find this description very confusing and unclear. 
please give me some direction to grasp it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you know what's a constant map is ? If you do, treat $1$ as a constant map with the constant being one. And $1/{2 \pi}$ is the normalizing term. In the second equality, they isolated the term in the square braces because that's exactly what the Fourier coefficient is on the interval $[0, 2 \pi].$

Comment: @ Fib1123 thanks, I understand it is a Gran Schmit process of getting the orthogonal projection of f(t) onto a subspace. However, I don't know why it is 1. also, which term has been normalized? I still got stuck with 1/2Pi

Comment: No need of Gram-Schmidt process. Inner product on $C[0,2 \pi]$ has been normalized. What do you mean by "why it is $1$ " ? You're taking the inner product of $f$ and $1$ on $C[0,2 \pi].$